# jsf 2 outputlink rendering method call without clicking

Tags: jsf

I am relatively new in jsf.

I have a jsf page someDetails.xhtml, in which I have an output link

```
<h:outputLink value="#{someTaskController.completeTask(taskId)}?taskId=#{taskId}">Assign Ticket</h:outputLink>
```

On clicking on this link, the method completeTask should be called and do something.

The problem is, when the jsf page    someDetails.xhtml is opened(in browser), the method    completeTask is getting called and does all the task, which should only happen on clicking the link.

What should I do ? Please help

Comment: the `h:outputLink` does not clicked but when evaluating the `value=""` attribute the `completeTask` method called .. check [this](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/).

Answer (score 1):

You're using the wrong tag for your purpose, use command link instead:

```
<h:commandLink value="Assign Ticket" action="#{someTaskController.completeTask()}">
  <f:param name="taskId" value="#{taskId}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

You can access taskId inside method completeTask() like this:

```
public void completeTask() {
  Map<String,String> params = 
            FacesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
  String taskId= params.get("taskId");
  // do your business action...
}
```